# Log4j only logs in main class. What I'm doing wrong?

Tags: java, logging, log4j

I'm currently struggling to log with log4j. I've created a xml configuration file and succeeded to log in my main class:

log4j.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE log4j:configuration SYSTEM "log4j.dtd">

<log4j:configuration xmlns:log4j="http://jakarta.apache.org/log4j/">

  <appender name="LogAppender" class="org.apache.log4j.FileAppender">
    <param name="file" value="logs/somelogfile.log" />
    <layout class="org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout">
      <param name="ConversionPattern" value="%d [%t] %p - %m%n" />
    </layout>
  </appender>

  <root>
    <priority value="ERROR" />
    <appender-ref ref="LogAppender" />
  </root>

</log4j:configuration>
```

My main class:

```
public class Main {

    static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(Main.class);
    /**
     * @param args
     */

    public static void main(String[] args) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        DOMConfigurator.configure("config/log4j.xml");

        logger.error("Hi");
    }

}
```

Unfortunatly, logging in other classes (in another package) doens't work. No matter if I call the DOMConfigurator or not, nothing is beeing logged. What I'm missing here? (Logger is always created with Logger.getLogger(Classname.class))

EDIT:

Sorry, I'm a dump! It's working. Just recognised, that I was catching the wrong exception in my other class, so that the logger was never called.

Comment: Just confirming...Have you created a logger in your DomConfigurator class? What's the logging level used there?

Comment: I haven't done anything else excepted writing the code shown in my question.

Comment: I dont see any problem in your code. looking at your configuration file it could the logger level which is configured for ERROR. so INFO and DEBUG statements may not gets logged. 

try changing the Logger level to DEBUG to get all INFO , DEBUG, ERROR levels

Answer (score 1):

You need to provision loggers in your log4j.xml file to point to appenders.  Here is an example:

```
<logger name="com.mycompany.apackage.MyClass">
  <level value="info"/>
  <appender-ref ref="appender-name-here" />
</logger>
```

Also, your root logger will only allow ERROR level logging (priority value="ERROR").